# in UIButton, the setImage and setBackgroudnImage content id different, it has rotate 90 degree

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibutton, rotation, setbackground

I have made a test about the UIButton, the button should show the capture buffer from camera, so i will set the image and backgroudimage for UIButton.
From the camera capture data, i set the image and backgroudn image, the image display is correct, but when i push the button and the background image has rotate 90 degree.
the test code is :

```
NSData *imagedata = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepesentation:buffer];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imagedata];
[galleryBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[galleryBtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But when i create a UIImage from the png data, the display is correct and no rotate.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];
```

Please help me.

Comment: Not i have use a UIImageView above the UIButton, and the set the UIIMageView content. But I do not know why the UIButton's image and background image will display different, even i set the same UIImage to this UIButton.

Comment: I have check the UIImage created from camera jpg result, the rotation is not 0, is 3.

Comment: I have try the other way to fixed this issue. To create an new UIImage from Graphics. And then to set the image and backgroundimage to UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the highlighted image state (as well as normal) as such:

```
[galleryBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[galleryBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Although this does hide any color highlighting that happens during the press by default.